# Features that characterize a track

Tags: gps, feature-detection

I have a series of track log, registerd with a gps tracker. I have to extract as may as possible features that identify that track. I have think about: length (obviously), bounds (the square obtained joining min latitude, min longitude, max latitude and max longitude), tortuosity, average speed, average elevation.

What features, best identify track in your opinion? There's something write in scientific licterature?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Title
- Distance
- List of all positions (lat, lon + alt + speed etc)
- Time (total)
- Moving time (time in motion)
- Max, avg, min speed
- Max, avg, min altitude
- Start/stop time
- Bounds
- Avg number of sats visible
- Avg C/No of these satellites
- Rms devation (avg)
- HDOP, VDOP avg.
- GPS/GLONASS/SBASS satellite visibility
- Number of successful fixes
- Time to first fix
- Speed/bearing spikes
- Tortuosity
- Minimum/Maximum time between two fixes
- Hear-rate ( Beats/min )
- Cadence (avg revolutions per minute)
- Temperature (avg)
- City, State (if you can get hold of this)
- Calories - if this is for walking tracks
- Track colour
- Error count
- Device name
- Track data format: (NMEA, gpx, etc)
- Tolerances (used for internal calculations, like epsilon in the [Douglas Peucker Algo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm)
- Track area
- Geo-fence perimeter (maybe an area of coordinates)

If you have the true path, it is even better as you can calculate:

- CEP
- RMS 2d - 67% or 98%
- CDF for Horizontal error
- CDF for [Along/ Cross track error](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#XTE)
- Number of position jumps, lead, lag.

If you find any doc, it'll be great, these are just from the top of my head.

Comment: Yes, it could be a good starting point.
I'm more intersted on track's feautures more than satellite information and info like DOP. Anyone with extra ideas is well accepted.